# How to compare the value of row in the DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datatable

I want to compare the value of the line name to determine the number of count (the same value)
I have tried following two approaches but they didn't match value count:

1.)

```
dataSet.Rows(i).ItemArray(0).ToString().Equals(dataSet.Rows(j).ItemArray(0).ToString())
```

2.)

```
dataSet.Rows(i).ItemArray(0).ToString()= dataSet.Rows(j).ItemArray(0).ToString()
```

Full code :

```
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To dataSet.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim r As DataRow = dtCloned.NewRow
    r(0) = dataSet.Rows(i).ItemArray(0).ToString()
    For j As Integer = 0 To dataSet.Rows.Count - 1
        If dataSet.Rows(i).ItemArray(0).ToString().Equals(dataSet.Rows(j).ItemArray(0).ToString()) Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
        r(1) = count
    Next
    dtCloned.Rows.Add(r)
Next
```

Comment: A `DataTable` should get a different name than `"dataSet"`.

Comment: What means "they didnt match value count"? In what way are they wrong? Can you provide samples?

Comment: It's also not that clear what you're actually trying to count, _"I want to compare the value of the line name to determine the number of count (the same value)"_ ??

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to like this.
I store the data contains all the data to the dataset (dataTable). I want to enter into dtClone (name column and count column), data that has sequence and no duplicates (name column) and fill the count column (contain the same number of digits in the name column).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to easily compare two rows:

```
    Dim comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of DataRow) = DataRowComparer.Default
    Dim RowEqual = comparer.Equals(ShowRow, OldRow)

    If (RowEqual = True) Then
         NavMessage = "Two rows are equal"
    Else
         NavMessage = "Two rows are not equal"
    End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Use For Each Loop To Compare Two data Table Value

Comment: Not helpful at all. OP is already using for-loops. In what way does a `For Each` help?

Comment: Riffer This Code<p>Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 4, 7}
Dim letters() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}

' Iterate through the list by using nested loops. 
For Each number As Integer In numbers
    For Each letter As String In letters
        Debug.Write(number.ToString & letter & " ")
    Next 
Next